# squid running out of sockets

Tags: linux, squid

I have a setup where squid sits in front of a java server and acts as a reverse proxy. Recently i've load tested the site and if i fire 100 threads at it each making a request using jmeter i start getting errors in my load test tool like 'no route to host' even though the load test tool and the server are on the same machine.

if i run the following command where port 82 is the port my squid server is running on:

```
netstat -ann | grep 82 | wc -l
```

i get 22000 or something and most of them are in TIMED_WAIT. i'm thinking that maybe the huge number of sockets in the TIMED_WAIT state are starving the box of resources.

Answer (score 2):

A handy answer from StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760819/is-there-a-limit-on-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-between-machines-on-linux

Comment: your comment helped me find this: http://www.speedguide.net/read_articles.php?id=121

TCP_TW_REUSE
This allows reusing sockets in TIME_WAIT state for new connections when it is safe from protocol viewpoint. Default value is 0 (disabled). It is generally a safer alternative to tcp_tw_recycle

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
(boolean, default: 0)

Note: The tcp_tw_reuse setting is particularly useful in environments where numerous short connections are open and left in TIME_WAIT state, such as web servers. Reusing the sockets can be very effective in reducing server load.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of different limits that can affect the operation of your Web proxy.  As sysadmin1138 mentioned, TCP connections is one of them.

Another, as Kyle managed to post before me, is the file descriptors.  SQUID's default, at least with 2.6, is 1024.  To increase this limit, you have to recompile increasing `--with-maxfd`.  Even after recompiled with higher FD, the `ulimit` will be in effect for the user starting squid.  For example to increase resource limit to 8192 run this before starting squid:

`ulimit -HSn 8192`

Linux defaults to pretty high on the kernel level these days, so you likely won't have to tune outside of SQUID for the FD.  If you provide log output, chances are it will indicate the exact issue, and we could provide more detailed recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

It could be too many open files With unix, "everything is a file", this includes sockets.  You either need to increase the max open files with `ulimit` for the user, or possibly in the kernel as well (`/proc/sys/fs/file-max`).  You could also play with the amount of time spent in TIME_WAIT with `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Squid 2.7, you can set the number of fd's available without recompiling;
  http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/max_filedescriptors/